# Structural impact of removing windows from formally exterior wall

Tags: walls, windows, structural

Our 1950s ranch on slab was added on to some time in the 1990s. A wall of rectangular windows that used to be a perimeter/outer wall, is now an interior wall. Surely it's structural, but are the windows integral to the structure? Can I remove the windows but keep the wood framing, and not risk the integrity? In photo, see 2 column grid of eight windows with blue wall of add-on space in distance. Thanks!

[image]

[image: roof tie in]

[image: add on room, looking back into original space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows themselves will not be structural, and in your case the wood in the middle between the 2 columns will not be either. I see in the picture the rafters over the windows appear to be the same dimension as the rafters of the rest of the ceiling. those rafters have no additional support under them so it is safe to assume that the rafters over the window section can carry the load of the roof on their own without the center post between the windows. The only exception that would be if the rafters were notched to accept the vertical post. That notch would weaken the rafter and not allow you to remove the wall unless the rafter was repaired or replaced.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Correct, none of the 20 or so rafters are supported mid way. There does not seem to be a notch on rafter at center column, so sounds like I can assume windows can be removed. In general, do you know if the glass in an arrangement such as this is ever intended to contribute to the load bearing?

Comment: In residences, typically- no, There are occasions where glass is used on floors of commercial buildings, I am sure there are other examples as well. In your case, it will not be used as structural.

Comment: +1 for considering connection from post to beam. (There’s no equipment on roof at that location, right?)

Comment: @LeeSam, You make a valid point about the potential of other loads on the roof. Your mention of roof mounted equipment brought to mind how the roof of the room in the distance was tied into or on top of that area in question, if it is at all...

Comment: @Jack, photos added. Exterior photo, new room comes in from the right. Does that provide enough detail about how it's tied in?

Comment: Is this other roof part of the original build or an addition?

Comment: @Jack, Left side is original. Right side is addition. The beams/rafters extend from interior to exterior, as can be seen in lower left corner of photo. But window wall rafter is integrated into the addition.

Comment: @LeeSam - Thanks for adding to the conversation. I've added some photos. No equipment on roof in that area.